# How to replace 'undefined' with an empty string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, undefined

I'm pulling in product data from an API. For more than half of the products, the product year doesn't exist. Instead, it returns as `undefined`.

Instead of displaying the word `undefined`, I'd like to replace it with an empty string.

Here's my code below:

```
product.photos.map(() => {
    let year = "";
    if (product.year === undefined) {
        year = product.year;
    }
    // Then output the data
    output += `
            <div class="card">
              <img class="img-fluid" src=${product.photos[0].text} alt=${product.model} />
              <h3>${product.year} ${product.manufacturer} ${product.model}</h3>
              <p>${product.hours} hours</p>
              <a href='https://used.battlefieldequipment.ca/en/${product["group-code"]}/${product["serial-number"]}' class="btn btn-primary">View Details</a>
            </div>         
        `;
});
```

Doesn't seem to work. How would I go about correcting this?

Comment: you have your assignment reversed

Comment: I think you meant to do `if (product.year !== undefined) {` (negating the expression). Alternative, you could use the 'falsy' mechanics of javascript to default to an empty string: `let year = product.year || "";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) inline in your output string.

```js
product.photos.map(() => {
    // output the data
    output += `
            <div class="card">
              <img class="img-fluid" src=${product.photos[0].text} alt=${product.model} />
              <h3>${product.year ?? ''} ${product.manufacturer} ${product.model}</h3>
              <p>${product.hours} hours</p>
              <a href='https://used.battlefieldequipment.ca/en/${product["group-code"]}/${product["serial-number"]}' class="btn btn-primary">View Details</a>
            </div>         
    `;
});
```

Comment: Thank you!! Never knew about this.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should use

```
product.year = product.year ?? ''
```

instead of

```
let year = "";
if (product.year === undefined) {
  year = product.year;
}
```

Comment: If `product` is a reference to an object somewhere else, then setting `product.year = ...` will change the underlying object, so be careful that this is not an unintended externality.